# Why does XHTML hate the eighth bit?

Tags: xhtml, non-ascii-characters

I noticed in one of my [xhtml](/questions/tagged/xhtml) files that the display material wouldn't go past a comment (you know, a code excerpt of the <!-- *** --> persuasion).  On closer scrutiny, I noticed that the comment contained a character not strictly within [7bit](/questions/tagged/7bit) "plain vanilla" [ascii](/questions/tagged/ascii) (the degree sign ° [&#xB0;], to be exact).  After changing the character to something a bit more "plain vanilla", the comment processed without a hitch and the display came out as expected.  This little experiment, however, left me with a couple of questions:

1. Why haven't I ever found any sort of documentation explaining why my XHTML compiler **hates** [non-ascii-characters](/questions/tagged/non-ascii-characters) (even relatively modest [8bit](/questions/tagged/8bit) characters like the degree sign and even when they're in comments)?
2. In some cases, confining oneself to [7bit](/questions/tagged/7bit) characters may prove misleading or otherwise incomprehensible to human proofreaders.  How then does one convince an XHTML compiler that coding an extra bit or two won't hurt it (at least not much;-)?

Thank you for clarifying this matter.

Comment: What encoding was the page in? If no encoding is specified, the browser assumes something (UTF-8, mostly) and a single byte with value 0xB0 is not a valid UTF-8 codepoint. Solution: Specify windows-1252 for an encoding or use `&#xB0;`

Comment: To answer your questions: 1) You are not using the correct search terms. Search with "encoding" or "charset", not "7bit". Also, the problem is not confined to XHTML. 2) It already does, the browser (with or without XHTML) supports all 1114112 Unicode codepoints.

Comment: Our correspondence gave me a big fat juicy idea...if the system _wants_ a valid UTF-8 codepoint, let's _give_ it a valid UTF-8 codepoint.  In this case, the combo '×°' ('x' can be replaced by any character with coding between &#xC2; and &#xDF; inclusive) shows in ANSI as characters '&#xD7;' + '&#xB0;', which _combine_ to form a valid UTF-8 codepoint ['&#xD7;' + '&#xB0;' -> ¹¹°1 0111 ¹°11 0000 = '&#b 0101 1111 0000' = &#x5F0; (which prints out of comment as the Hebrew double vav ligature [certified kosher?]).  NERDHOOD RULES (but if it had any sense, it would abdicate;-)

Comment: I've been using the Notepad utility to actually write my code.  What _it_ has is ANSI, UTF-8, Unicode, and Unicode big-endian (-; curse you, Blefuscu ;-).  I rather prefer the discipline of "plain vanilla" for _working_ (X)HTML/Javascript with maybe a pinch of ANSI for comment material specifically for _human_ edification (-; not for the monkey ;-).  Portability is probably going to kick me in the tuchis, but that's not so much of an issue now.

Comment: It doesn't really matter which standard you adhere to, as long as you adhere to a consistent standard! So if you save your files in Notepad with the ANSI encoding (a.k.a. Windows-1252), make sure the browser knows it's that particular encoding, by specifying `<meta charset="Windows-1252">` explicitly.

Comment: Of course people will tell you it's better to use UTF-8, and, well, it is, objectively. It allows you to write things like ← → ↑ ↓ directly instead of those pesky references in HTML. But the more important thing is to make sure every application speaks the same language. _Which_ language is of lesser concern.